# Get Business Object back from Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, business-objects

What exactly is the e.Row.DataItem return.. MSDN says.. **returns An Object that represents the underlying data object to which the GridViewRow object is bound.**

Here is my DataGrid...

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PracticeCode" HeaderText="PracticeCode" SortExpression="PracticeCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountNo" HeaderText="AccountNo" SortExpression="AccountNo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientName" HeaderText="PatientName" SortExpression="PatientName" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And I bind it with my Business Object **List < Patient >**..  In the row DataBound event, I try this...

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Patient p1 = (Patient)e.Row.DataItem;
        Label lbl = e.Row.FindControl("LblStatus") as Label;

        if (p1 == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("P1 is null");
        }

        if (p1.OpenItems.Count > 0)
        {
            lbl.Text = "Has open Items";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

I get the exception **P1 is null**... Why so...  What am I missing..

**Note** : There could be other ways to accomplish this, but I'm looking especially why my p1 is null...  and is there any way to get the **Patient** Object back from GridView after binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RowDataBound is called for the header and footer also, you need to make sure your currently in an actual `DataRow` before calling `e.Row.DataItem`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {                
       if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          return;

       Patient p1 = (Patient)e.Row.DataItem;
```

Comment: Yeah well it's not THAT obvious that this event is also called for the header... it would have make sense euther ways